# MATCH in SQLite FTS

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I use FTS in SQLite, I have data:

> abc
>   def
>   go to
>   to go
>   jdk
>   sqlite
>   let go
>   go on
>   going to
>   not going

I use query: `select * from table where columns MATCH 'go*'`. RESULT:

> go to
>   to go
>   let go
>   go on
>   going to
>   not going

But I want result `go to, go on`, how to query?

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) explains, `go*` is a prefix search and finds any words that begin with `go`.

You want to search for two words, so in theory, you have to do a phrase search.
However, `"go *"` does not work because a prefix search needs an actual prefix.

Your best bet would be to search for the word `go` and, in your code, filter out any returned records where `go` occurs only at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where columns MATCH 'go*'
```

Match all **phrases** that **contain** any **single word** which **start with** *go*

> **go** to
>
> **go**ing to
>
> here we **go**
>
> ...

```
select * from table where columns MATCH 'go'
```

Match all **phrases** that **contain** any **single word** which **equal** *go*

> **go** to
>
> here we **go**
>
> ...

```
select * from table where columns MATCH '"^go"'
```

Match all **phrases** that **start with** a **single word** which **equal** *go*

> **go** to
>
> **go** in
>
> ...

Someone ansewers **'^go'** but it does not work, the magic is **' "^go" '**

Answer (score 1):

What also might help a bit is using '^go' which will only give you the entrys which beginn with go (supported from sqlite version  3.7.9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where columns MATCH '^go *'
```

This will give the result:
    go to, go on

```
select * from table where columns MATCH '^go*'
```

This will give the result:
go to, go on, going to